# "Can't find variable: cordova"

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to import some plugins, in order to use them onto my Cordova application. After doing some tests, I got stuck at the following error from the debugger on my web browser console (served by ionic):

> Can't find variable: cordova signup@http://localhost:8100/js/controllers.js:223:32

And this is the line corresponding to the error:

> var Sim_plugin = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/sim");

I tried to search everywhere about the problems related to this issue: But didn't yet find any solution that might solve my problem.

I need some help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please note, that you can't use the most plugins in your local browser. They only runs on device

Answer (score 0):

Did you include *cordova.js* in your *index.html*?

```
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

And you have to inject *ionic* into your angular app

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', ['ionic']);
```

Comment: **cordova.js** is already included within index.html. But concerning the app js module: I'm using the following code: **angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives','ngCordova'])**.